# laravel 42522 exception column not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

this is my code

```
$model = Admin::create(Input::only('username', 'password', 'mobileNumber', 'firstName', 'lastName'));
echo $model->ID;
exit;
```

and the table `admin` has just one more column which is `ID` and it is primary key and auto increment

I got this exception:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `admin` (`username`, `password`,
>   `firstName`, `lastName`, `mobileNumber`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values (samdari, azurial, samoad, adfasdf, 55545454, 2014-06-17
>   21:01:21, 2014-06-17 21:01:21))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to your `Admin` model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Set to true if you want to automatically have `created_at` and `updated_at` fields, then create another migration for your table and add the columns in like this:

```
Schema::table('admin', function($table) {
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

You can see more in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps) section about Disabling Auto Timestamps

Comment: I don't have `created at` and `updated at` columns in my database. Plus, I don't want to have them. so is just setting the `$timestamp` variable to `false` is enough?

Comment: why do people downvote this question please? I have a problem I tried to solve it but I couldn't. what wrong have I done?

Comment: yes. laravel (for whatever reason) assumes that you want them, so you have to disable them if you dont.

Comment: @Simeoni not sure, people are free to vote how they wish, and I think according to the help guide this is a good candidate question, though some people may feel that there are duplicates of this one out there.

Comment: I feel bad because I tried to google this problem and I couldn't find the solution myself and I then tried to check the database and there is no missing column. Thus, I did try, but how could I know that laravel automatically added these two fields (update, create) that is why I am sad of users on this site